# How to use array of another view controller class?

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables, swift2

I need to use the `order` array in another class (`AddOrderVievContoller.swift` class)

```
class OrderListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var orders: [Order] = []
```

> error message in AddOrderVievContoller.swift class: use of unresolved indentifier 'orders'

```
if results != nil {
    orders = results as! [Order]
}
```

Comment: well, get hold of of an instance of the `OrderListViewController` inside your `AddOrderVievContoller` to get its `orders` value.

Comment: How are they related? You should have some callback if the view controller is requesting data from something else and particularly if the response is asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a global variable:

`public var orders = [String]()`

place this in-between the *modules* your importing (`import UIKit`) and the class definition:

```
import UIKit

public var orders = [String]()

class OrderListViewController: UITableViewController {


//viewDidLoad, etc. 
}
```

Then you can access the `orders` array in different viewControllers as you're currently trying to do.