# Swift save an array of strings to NSUserdefaults and reuse for notification.alertbody text

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, notifications, nsuserdefaults

i am working on a notification project, see this: [Swift notification fire from datePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246572/swift-notification-fire-from-datepicker/34249306?noredirect=1#comment56246663_34249306)

The problem is this: i have a variable

```
item = news.titleNews
```

(in ViewController.Swift) that is a list of strings like this:

one

two

three

etc..

i am converting this variable to an array like this:

```
myArray = [item]
```

and saving to NSUserDefaults like that:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myArray, forKey:"myArray")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

then in settings.swift if i put:

```
 localNotification.alertBody = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("myArray")
```

i receive only nil...or if i pass through NSUserdefaults only item string my notification is only one corresponding to first string! i want a notification for each string of my strings list.
Thank you in advance for the Help.

Comment: If you want a notification for each string in your array then you will need to loop through the array and create a notification for each string

Comment: Also, don't use NSUserDefaults to pass values between objects unless there is a need to persist the values between runs of your app; even then NSUserDefaults isn't necessarily the best persistence method.  Create properties on your view controllers and assign these as required.

Comment: i can't loop through the array because strings are variable, generated by a parser...I can't create an instance of the array on my settings.swift controller because i obtain the error "array out of range"...

Comment: I don't see why you can't loop through the array just because the number is variable; that is what `array.count` gives you.  If you get array out of range exception then you haven't set the array property correctly.

Comment: i partially solved creating a public variable like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33900240/how-to-use-array-of-another-view-controller-class  .  Now if i write this:  localNotification.alertBody = news[0].titleNews  i get the notification only for the first string. There is a method to call more index at time like for example this news[0,1,2].titleNews?

Comment: solved creating a localNotification2 constant and give it the value news[2].titleNews and so on.

Comment: Just use a for loop, creating a new notification each time inside the loop